# wcf: debugging native c++ dll?

Tags: c#, c++, wcf

I run a WCF-Service in IIS-Express 8.0 and use Visual Studio 2010. The service calls a C++/CLI Wrapper, which calls the native C++ dll. If I start the client (C# Application), I am able to debug client, service and wrapper. If I try to step from the wrapper into the native C++ - Code, I fail. But from the return code I can see, that the  function in the native C++ dll was called. 
In Addition: The native C++ dll is delay loaded from a path, I configure in the service via Global.asax-File. I also tried to add the .pdb - File of native dll, but it didn't help.

Does anyone know, which settings must be made to step into the c++ Code?

Thanks, Moka

Comment: Is the native C++ DLL .NET?  Do you have the project for that DLL?  I believe you'll need the source code to step into it, and it would have to be .NET.

Comment: No, the native C++ - dll is not .NET, its frp, a

Comment: ... its from a C++-Project. If I call a C#-Application instead of the service, I can debug Wrapper and Native C++ dll.

Answer (score 2):

In any instance of Visual Studio, select Debug | Attach to Process, the process list find the pertinent instance of iisexpress.exe, then ensure you have both "Managed (v4.0) code, Native code" selected in the Attach To textbox.

EDIT:  easier method that works with your web app project:  go to project settings for the web app project which is hosting the WCF service, on the Web tag, scroll down find the the Debuggers checkboxes, and ensure that Native Code is also selected.

Comment: Thank you Chris. If I attach the iiexpress.exe manually and select both types of code, I can debug the native code.